# Send Selected File Information to SharePoint Form in Dialog Box

Tags: sharepoint, webforms, modal-dialog, selecteditem

I currently have a custom button in my SharePoint 2013 ribbon which should open a dialog box with a form. The button is only enabled when two or more files are selected. I would like to know how to send information about the selected files to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the selected files/item information to the form using query string parameters.
When u add custom action, in element.xml there is CommanUIHandler element in which you can define tokens as query string parameters to be replaced when custom action is clicked.

{SelectedItemId} and {ItemId} tokens can be your use.

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ff458385.aspx